# SQL Server Combining queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a user's total visits number for each web URL page that is stored in my database.
Bellow is my SQL query that will show total unique users where URL contains that keyword.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userId) as someUrlTitleTotalVisitors
FROM someTable
WHERE urlCol LIKE '%someUrlKeyword%'
```

Now I have 50+ more pages to go, example:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userId) as anotherUrlTitleTotalVisitors
FROM someTable
WHERE urlCol LIKE '%anotherUrlKeyword%'
```

.etc..

I would assume that I don't need to write 50+ separate queries for each URL title, and I should be able to get all data with one call.

So, my question is how can I combine this query as one?

Comment: You are gonna have a problem after `Url-Title-9`. And, on a more serious comment, do you have that list of Urls on a table?

Comment: No, this is just for an example. All url keywords are unique and not alike each other. Table, columns and url links are all made up for my question post.

Comment: And, do you have the list of Urls that you want to analyze on some table?

Comment: I dont have full URL paths, just some unique URL keywords that will identify pages Im trying to track.

Comment: Ok, then, to clarify, do you have those unique keywords that you want to track stored on some table?

Comment: If you place the patterns in a table then you can `JOIN` with that table to get the desired results.

Comment: You will need some sort of pattern for grouping similar URLs, if you can't just simply group each unique URL. Is there a pattern you can group on? If we had a better sample of URLs, we may be able to give you a pattern to use for grouping.

Comment: @crashtestxxx You should, otherwise you are looking to a where with 50 `LIKE`s. On a table, you would only need a join.

Comment: Please post some sample data from urlCol. I think that will give us more to go by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, if you don't have those keywords that you want to check on a table, then sadly, you are looking on a query like this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN urlCol LIKE '%Url-Title-1%' THEN 'Url-Title-1'
        WHEN urlCol LIKE '%Url-Title-2%' THEN 'Url-Title-2'
        WHEN urlCol LIKE '%Url-Title-3%' THEN 'Url-Title-3'
        WHEN urlCol LIKE '%Url-Title-4%' THEN 'Url-Title-4'
        ..... END Url,
        COUNT(DISTINCT userId)  TotalVisitors
FROM someTable
WHERE urlCol LIKE '%Url-Title-1%'
OR urlCol LIKE '%Url-Title-2%'
OR urlCol LIKE '%Url-Title-3%'
OR urlCol LIKE '%Url-Title-4%'
.....
GROUP BY CASE WHEN urlCol LIKE '%Url-Title-1%' THEN 'Url-Title-1'
         WHEN urlCol LIKE '%Url-Title-2%' THEN 'Url-Title-2'
         WHEN urlCol LIKE '%Url-Title-3%' THEN 'Url-Title-3'
         WHEN urlCol LIKE '%Url-Title-4%' THEN 'Url-Title-4'
         ..... END
```

Now, if you could put those keywords on a table, your query would be like this:

```
SELECT  B.KeyWord,
        COUNT(DISTINCT userId)  TotalVisitors
FROM someTable A
INNER JOIN TableWithKeywords B
ON A.urlCol LIKE '%' + B.KeyWord + '%'
GROUP BY B.KeyWord
```

quite a difference, right?, and you could add or remove keywords on that table without touching your query, very handy.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your advise for putting keywords in the separate table, I will definitely do that.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to group by URL:

```
SELECT urlCol, COUNT(DISTINCT userId) as title1TotalVisitors
FROM someTable
GROUP BY urlCol
```

Comment: Apparently, op here wants to test keyword of url, so, most likely he doesn't want to group by the entire Url. (That's why he's using `LIKE`)

Comment: Yeah, added a comment above asking for clarification. We can't come up w/ a grouping without knowing more about his URLs.

Comment: I would have to insert URL keywords manually, because they are all different.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userId) as title1TotalVisitors,urlCol 
FROM someTable
WHERE urlCol LIKE '%Url-Title-[1-50]%'
Group by urlCol
```

Comment: Op said on a comment that those Urls were just examples, not reality.

Comment: Sorry If I was not clear, URL keywords are all different - %ABCD%, %ZWOY%, they are not similar like.